# Sending bulk email from google compute engine

Tags: email, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I don't know much about mail servers but i would like to know whether I can send bulk email from google compute engine in any possible way.By bulk mail i mean same mail (around 3 million per day)  to different email address according to the completion of assigned job.It's almost like notification to users whether their work is complete or not.I can spent time learning about mail servers if this is achievable else it waste of time for me at the moment.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question. As far as I am aware, your question does not belong to this community.

Answer (score 0):

By default Google Compute Engine doesn't allow emails to be sent from it's servers. In order to do this you will need to use a 3rd party email relay service. Google has partnered with Sendgrid, though you can use any email service provider. Here are the instructions for sending email with sendgrid from your compute engine. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/

You also get extra allotment free for using Google.

If you need to send that many emails, it may be better for you to look at AWS SES 
If you wanted to send 3 million per day from Sendgrid, it would cost you ~$1,200 per day  Though at that scale you might as well look for custom pricing or other vendors.

Mandrill would cost you $36,000/per month (90 million emails)

Comment: "If you don't have a Google Apps account or don't want to use Google Apps or a third-party mail provider(SendGrid, Mailgun, or Mailjet), you can set up your own email server on an instance using a non-standard port. You can choose any ephemeral port that isn't blocked by Compute Engine."
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/
anyone tried this method ?